# Is it possible to only define just one changing property in @media?

Tags: css

So, for instance I have:

```
#headerMain {
    position: fixed;
    width: 100%;
    background: rgba(255,255,255,.9);
    z-index: 999999999;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

I just want to change the position property when going to a mobile:

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 480px) {
  #headerMain {
    position: absolute;
  }
}
```

Or do I need to specify all properties?

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 480px) {
  #headerMain {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    background: rgba(255,255,255,.9);
    z-index: 999999999;
    overflow: hidden;
  }
}
```

Thank you in advance!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can simply overwrite a single declaration when using a media query.  A simple example:

```
#headerMain {
  background: blue;
  color: white;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 480px) {
  #headerMain {
    background: red;
  }
}
```

When the viewport is larger than 480px, the text will be white and the background will be blue. When the viewport is smaller than 480px (you can make this happen by just changing the size of your browser window), the background will be red, but the text will remain white.

This is because of the *cascading* part of CSS. In a less-than-480px-wide viewport, the element inherits both `#headerMain` declarations, and the more specific media query (`@media only screen and (max-width: 480px)`) overrides the background-color to make it red.